# bash find command refuses to find more than one file with wildcard

Tags: bash, find, wildcard

My `find` is not working the way I expected. When there is more than one file it halts with error.

```
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$ ll
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 hpek  staff    70B Mar  2 15:16 f1.tex
-rw-r--r--  1 hpek  staff    70B Mar  2 15:17 f2.tex
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$ find . -name *.tex 
find: f2.tex: unknown option
hpek@melda:
```

and if I remove one of the files, then it works:

```
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$ rm f1.tex 
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$ find . -name *.tex 
./f2.tex
hpek@melda:~/temp/test$
```

It does not matter what file I remove. As soon as the wildcard gives more than one file, then `find` halts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*.tex` is expanded by bash before sent as argument to the command.

```
find . -name *.tex
```

is in your case equivalent to

```
find . -name f1.tex f2.tex
```

**Solution:** Put `"..."` around arguments with wildcards to avoid the shell expansion:

```
find . -name "*.tex"
```

This will work as expected:

```
$ find . -name "*.tex"
./f1.tex
./f2.tex
```

Comment: I have never had any problems with `find` before. Can it be that something has happened to my shell!? -or is it standard to expand wildcard before pasing argument?

Comment: Well, that's exactly how globs ("wildcards") work. Take ls for example: It has no idea what `*.tex` means so it relies on the shell doing the expansion for it. find is an exception here because it has more advanced needs and wants to do the expansion on its own.

Answer (score 4):

You have to quote the wildcards so bash doesn't expand them:

```
find . -name '*.tex'
```

Right now `*` is being interpreted by bash. As a result, this is the actual command being executed:

```
find . -name f1.tex f2.text
```

Comment: Actually it is `find . -name f1.tex f2.tex` in the original case, which causes the "unknown option" error.

Answer (score 3):

Your wildcard `*` is being expanded by the shell before reaching the `find` command. In other words, here's the command executed by `find`:

```
find . -name f1.tex f2.tex
```

Note that if you execute the command from a different directory, you will get different results since the wildcard will be expanded differently.

In order to get the desired result, try escaping it like this:

```
find . -name \*.tex
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `find . -name "*.tex"` instead – Note the quotation marks around the glob. What is happening here is that in your case, your shell is expanding the glob and then passing the result of that to find, which results in `find . -name f1.tex f2.tex` – Which is not a valid way of using find.

By putting the argument in quotation marks, it gets passed to find as is.